# Too many SE sites are leading to increased answer time

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are we creating too many the different stackexchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77971/are-we-creating-too-many-the-different-stackexchange-sites)

i read other questions regarding this but i need more clarification so thats why i started new thread

I am feeling that having too many SE sites wasting more time , at least for me:

1. I asked question of linux , shell in SO and they migrated to unix and linux In in So and i usually get answer in less than 5-8 mins but there i had to wait for 2 hrs. Although some will say that go to help desk if u need urgently buy till SO is my help desk and working more than good
2. Someone was saying that its better to diff sites so that persons which r more expert can concentrate only on that . But i think for that requirements , tags will work very fine. I agree cooking and Linux are differnet thing but programming , linux , windows all can come under one site. othwise soon you have to have as many sites as number of tags
3. usually every IT person knows windows , linux , computer. Although person may be working currently in one field , but he may be the master in other fields as well .He can answer many fields . so for that person , how many sites he will asnwer. We may be depriving some users from his technical knowledge . Although may not always true , but there r chances.
4. last things is If SO owner want to have diff sites thats ok , but if someone is asking in SO , it should stay there

Its like same like when i used to categorise ebooks in computer . intially it was 5 folders but then i used diff subjects and then i had 30 folders and the i never searched from there , rather i find internet good

Comment: Please clarify "clarifictaion" :)

Comment: You're about the 400th person to say this, only the 399 people before you were considerably easier to understand

Comment: SO is _not_ a Help Desk!

Comment: Any links to those ques

Comment: @Wether so it means if it is , then every effort will be made not to make it

Comment: good point, though I don't know what the correct solution is. If a question is about Unix, it should be moved to Unix site. The problem is that SO has larger community, so that question maybe answered faster here

Comment: Indeed, @Wether is right. And any question that might turn the Stack Exchange sites from being a good resource of questions and answers into some help forum, will (should) be deleted. But that would apply to *all* sites, no matter if it were one big sites or a collection of many specialized sites.

Comment: @Arjan **whitespace before punctuation** ha ha looks u have done lot of report writing

Comment: Well, @Mirror, it not only looks odd (and to me even *careless*), but also makes regular web browsers think they can wrap a line there.

Comment: @Arjan actually till now MS Word had been helping me this ;)

Comment: Might be suitable for other languages, @Mirror51, [but even in French](http://french.about.com/library/writing/bl-punctuation.htm) it's not used for commas and periods, though they use some sort of whitespace before some other punctuation. I've never seen it in any English dialect though.

Comment: @Arjan u r right , i will be careful next time

Comment: Okay, then I will complain about the "u r" and the lowercase "i" next time! ;-)

Comment: roflmfao.. We are all arguing over such trivial things like grammar here. I'm going to save a copy of this page and read it everyday after work for the next 3 days. The good laugh will be very stress releasing. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

The StackExchange sites are deliberately verticals, based on interest/knowledge areas. For example, I **would not want** questions about how to configure linux for a desktop filling up SO, even if I knew the answer (which I don't).

Having a tighter focus allows knowledge experts for (or people interested in) each area to see and answer your question *quicker* if anything.

There is perhaps some debate over the level of granularity there, though - with some kind of overlap pehaps between superuser, ubuntu and apple, for example; but if you consider the entire set of [stackexchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), the decision to divide is pretty obvious and sane.

Comment: Plus, though I don't really like the separation between SU, Ask Ubuntu, Unix.se, Apple.se and all, even then: asking *on topic* questions on one of those will not likely get it migrated to one of the others. But surely posting an *off topic* question on SO will put your question in the hands of those who vote for migration. If one's question then ends up on a lower traffic site, then one cannot really complain about that, I think.

Comment: i think SO, SU, SF were enough , all others are variations of it

Comment: @Mirror really? English? Parenting? DIY?

Comment: i was talking bout computer stuff only.