# Feedback from the community when applying dupe hammer

Tags: feature-request, dupehammer

I try to weld my dupe hammer carefully - honest I do. I'm well aware which tags I can use it in, and I do not agree that [I need reminding when it's about to be used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231625/please-remind-me-when-i-am-wielding-the-dupe-hammer).

I do, however, sometimes wonder whether I've used it appropriately. I try to keep an eye on most questions where I've used it to keep an eye out for the OP (or someone else) commenting along the lines of "That's not a duplicate"/"That's not answering my question"/"You're an idiot" and sometimes I've just re-opened the question.

I wish there was some feedback loop in place like there is with questions/answers (and to a lesser extent, comments) where the community can be proactive in telling me I've been an idiot-with-a-dupe-hammer.

I wondered what people might think about some (or all) users being able to provide me with feedback when I dupe hammer. Perhaps something as simple as a "good call"/"bad call" button next to the close-as-dupe message.

There could be some feedback to the closer, such as >3 "bad call" and the user gets an inbox message along the lines of

> 3 users have indicated that they think your close as duplicate is incorrect.

Is this a useful feature, or pointless?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88501/community-approval-disapproval-votes-on-close-votes

Comment: Oh for pete sake, I searched and everything. Someone dupe hammer this! (Except, one saving grace, that was way before the dupe-hammer existed. Perhaps now that one person welds the power this is needed)